# processing json with fetch returns undefined for valid json key

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fetch

I need to request data from my REST server to populate my UI (frontend). In doing so, I need to request some data from my and other servers. One such request is to get a list of states (provinces), process each one and add them to a `select` HTML component. I use [fetch()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663899/4628115) and [.json()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664206/4628115) amongst other tools to do this.

**Problem:**

In calling my REST server for json data, I receive the following data (taken from Chrome console):

```
{provinces:[Eastern Cape,Mpumalanga,Western Cape,Gauteng,KwaZulu Natal,North West,Northern Cape,Free 
State,Limpopo]}
```

I intend to add each of these as an option to a `select`. While attempting to acquire the value for the `provinces` key, I get `undefined`.

I am making this call using:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces").then(e => e.json()).then(e => console.log(e.provinces));
```

Further, since I can directly refer to json keys using the `[]` operator, I attempt this using

```
fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces").then(e => e.json()).then(e => console.log(e['provinces']));
```

which as you may have guessed aswel, also returns undefined.

For the record, the full Chrome Console output is

```
Promise {<pending>}
undefined
```

Looking over some SO examples, I believe my call(s) may be correct, this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37121496/4628115), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664029/4628115) one, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48842213/4628115) one all which confirm its validity.

**What else have I tried:**

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663899/4628115) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664206/4628115) suggested to use the json data response inside of the same `then()` call e.g.

```
fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces").then(e => {
    e.json().then(s => {
        console.log(s['provinces']);
 });
});
```

and

```
fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces").then(e => {
    e.json().then(s => {
        console.log(s.provinces);
 });
});
```

both which return:

```
Promise {<pending>}
undefined
```

**What am I missing / doing wrong?**

---

**Update**

Screenshot of Chrome console in order of commands listed above:

[image]

**Resource file** [za-province-city.json](https://github.com/dirkstrauss/SouthAfrica/blob/master/SouthAfricanCities.json)

**NodeJS express code:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const raw = fs.readFileSync("./res/za-province-city.json");
const map = JSON.parse(raw);
const mapProvinceCity = {};
map.forEach(item => {
    if (!mapProvinceCity.hasOwnProperty(item.ProvinceName)) {
        mapProvinceCity[item.ProvinceName] = [];
    }
    mapProvinceCity[item.ProvinceName].push(item.City);
});
for (let key in mapProvinceCity) {
    mapProvinceCity[key].sort((a, b) => a.toLocaleString().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase()));
}

router.get('/location/provinces', function (req, res, next) {
    let strings = Object.keys(mapProvinceCity);
    let json = JSON.stringify({provinces: strings}).replace(/"/g, '');
    return res.json(json);
});

router.get('/location/:province/cities', function (req, res, next) {
    let province = req.param('province');
    let cities = mapProvinceCity[province];
    let json = JSON.stringify({cities: cities}).replace(/"/g, '');
    return res.json(json);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Note: if you are wondering about the `replace()`, each time I requested data in postman, I got

[image]

Comment: _"I receive the following data  (taken from Chrome console)"_  where? What particular `console.log()` line produced that result?

Comment: Is the data you're getting back exactly as you've included here? Because that's not valid json. (No quotes.) If that's what's being returned from the server, the `e.json()` call is probably throwing.

Comment: @Phil adding screenshots, give me a sec

Comment: @rayhatfield see above comment

Comment: A screenshot of the console might be helpful but what I'd really like to see is the code that produces it

Comment: @Phil yeah - it was my mistake - will post answer now

Comment: @rayhatfield see above comment

Comment: Oh   looks like you are running the fetch in console and that's why you see the pending promise because that's what it returns.

Comment: What on Earth are you doing with that string replace? Also, you're double-encoding your mangled JSON so in the end, it will just be an unusable string. Just use `res.json({provinces: strings})`

Comment: @Phil it has been a while since I last worked with this ;). See my answer

Answer (score 3):

I think your issues all stem from a misunderstanding of Express' [`res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json).

This is basically a shortcut for

```js
res.set("Content-type: application/json")
res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data))
```

I imagine your problems started when you thought you needed to *stringify* your data. What happens then is that your data is double-encoded / double stringified, hence the extra quotes. Removing the quotes though mangles your data.

`console.log()` is not a particularly good debugging tool as it obfuscates a lot of information. In your code, `s` is actually a string

```
"{provinces:[Eastern Cape,Mpumalanga,...]}"
```

I suggest you use the actual [debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) instead.

---

The simple solution is to use `res.json()` as intended

```js
router.get('/location/provinces', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.json({ provinces: Object.keys(mapProvinceCity) });
});
```

with your client-side code looking like

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces")
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw res
    }
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Provinces:', data.provinces)
  })
```

This goes for all your Express routes. Do **not** use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: You are correct about the `res.json()` being a shortcut for the header, etc. I recall going through that not to long ago. Hopefully it all comes back to me pretty soon :)